# FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path /ROOT. Deploy plugin of jenkins failling to deploy

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, jenkins

Attempting to set up jenkins and its container deploy plugin.

However, I am receiving the following stacktrace :

```
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [/myHome/jenkins/jobs/myAPP/workspace/target/ROOT.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:111)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:187)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:60)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:86)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:784)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:766)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:45)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:700)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:675)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$RunnerImpl.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:998)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:622)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1429)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:481)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:238)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path /ROOT
```

Which isn't really that helpful, I can deploy manually using tomcat manager, and also copying the war file across using command line options works. But i can not get the automated deploy to work.

I am using a tomcat url of `http://localhost:8080/` and the deploy fails when their is no app currently deployed.

Any help gratefully received, thanks.

Comment: First increase Jenkins log verbosity to info - you may get an hint. Partial copy of the WAR file, lacking web.xml, file system permissions like ACLs, disk space full...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a wild guess but the ROOT context is not: /ROOT but rather / maybe there is something wrong in your config

Answer (score 4):

Its a ContainerExc not fileNotFound; therefore the war file has been located.

URL should be `http://localhost:8080`

Is userName and Password provided?

Is this userName assigned a role of manager-script?

is the tomcat webapp cleared down once for work and temp folder?

If YES to above all, now run the tomcat without any war fiel present in the webapps folder and open a web broswer to see `http://localhost:8080` is accessible. 
Now whilst this tomcat running, build the jenkins job and deployment should be fine.