# Jenkins deploy plugin is deploying to tomcat but not starting the app

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins

Is there a way for jenkins to deploy and also start the app ?

[Related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9001601/106261) I have had to rename my war file from ROOT, to an arbitrary name for the deploy to be (somewhat) succesful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't replace the `ROOT` webapp by autodeployment which is what you would do. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application) for the ways to do replace the root wepapp. Which, I assume, is not what you want to do.

Comment: no, I renamed my application to ROOT and deleted the tomcat default, so that the url of my app was shorter; its pretty normal I think. It works fine when not using jenkins.

Comment: I don't think it is pretty normal. In my view normal is a virtual host configuration or an Apache HTTPd proxy that cares for shorter URLs.